# Help understanding notation in formula for LR test (multinomial distribution)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

Clumsy first post - apologies for any wrong doing on my part. For context, below the excerpt of the text where the formula appears:

[image]

Could anyone kindly help explain what formula (1.4) means?

$$\large\color{red}{\inf_{p\in \Lambda_0}\sup_{\pi\in\Lambda}}\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^{(N)}\log\frac{\pi_i}{p_i}$$

The part I don't understand is in red, I would appreciate help in interpreting it.

Apologies for the lack of know-how on posting code in Math Jax format - I am trying to figure it out - pointers on the latter (mac) hugely appreciated